# Wordpress hierarchical drop down menus for a taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have been trying to make a hierarchical dropdown where the first dropdown will select Level 1 for a taxonomy.

On selection another dropdown will show the associated Level 2 only options for that level.

Again on selection another dropdown will show the associated level 3 only options for that level and so on.

I managed to do the following, which works well, only that the childOf id is hardcoded but I want to get it from the previous selection. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    <h3>Filter by:</h3>
                    <form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>" method="get">
                        <div>
                            <?php
                                $page_sections = get_taxonomy('collection');

                                $select = wp_dropdown_categories(array(
                                'show_option_all' =>  __("Show All {$page_sections->label}"),
                                'taxonomy'        =>  'collection',
                                'name'            =>  'location',
                                'orderby'         =>  'name',
                                'hierarchical'    =>  true,
                                'depth'           =>  1,
                                'show_count'      =>  false,  // This will give a view
                                'hide_empty'      =>  true,   // This will give false positives, i.e. one's not empty related to the other terms. TODO: Fix that
                                ));

                            $page_sections = get_taxonomy('collection');


                        wp_dropdown_categories(array(
                            'show_option_all' =>  __("Show All {$page_sections->label}"),
                            'child_of' =>  '3',
                            'taxonomy'        =>  'collection',
                            'name'            =>  'repository',
                            'orderby'         =>  'name',
                            'hierarchical'    =>  true,
                            'depth'           =>  1,
                            'show_count'      =>  false,  // This will give a view
                            'hide_empty'      =>  true,   // This will give false positives, i.e. one's not empty related to the other terms. TODO: Fix that
                     ));

$page_sections = get_taxonomy('collection');
$term = get_queried_object();

wp_dropdown_categories(array(
                    'show_option_all' =>  __("Show All {$page_sections->label}"),
                    'child_of' =>  '7',
                    'taxonomy'        =>  'collection',
                    'name'            =>  'fond',
                    'orderby'         =>  'name',
                    'hierarchical'    =>  true,
                    'depth'           =>  1,
                    'show_count'      =>  false,  // This will give a view
                    'hide_empty'      =>  true,   // This will give false positives, i.e. one's not empty related to the other terms. TODO: Fix that
                
                ));
$term = get_queried_object();
wp_dropdown_categories(array(
                    'show_option_all' =>  __("Show All {$page_sections->label}"),
                    'child_of' => '8',
                    'taxonomy'        =>  'collection',
                    'name'            =>  'series',
                    'orderby'         =>  'name',
                    'hierarchical'    =>  true,
                    'depth'           =>  1,
                    'show_count'      =>  false,  // This will give a view
                    'hide_empty'      =>  true,   // This will give false positives, i.e. one's not empty related to the other terms. TODO: Fix that
                
                ));
                            ?>
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="filter" /> <!--CHANGE VALUE TO YOUR LIKING!-->
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: $term->parent should return parent id if thats what you are trying to do.

Comment: Are you referring to $term = get_queried_object();? I want that the first  wp_dropdown_categories whose name is location when selected will be able to populate the second wp_dropdown_categories with the children of the location selected and so on

Comment: child_of => $term->parent // should return 3,7 or 8 as for your example

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work